# Using Merge statement into a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, merge

This is the table I'm going to use for the trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE "grace_period" (
    "id"    NUMBER(11)  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "id_user"   NUMBER(20)  NOT NULL,
    "date_limit"    DATE    NOT NULL,
    "active"    NUMBER(11),
    "created_at"    DATE    NOT NULL,
    "updated_at"    DATE    
);
```

And what I would like to do is to create a trigger before insert that checks if the new entry already contains `"id_user"`.

If `"id_user"` exists then make an update on `"active"` column for that `"id_user"` and if it doesn't exist it should insert a new row.

---

I managed to create the merge into a trigger (this trigger is going to be used until I integrate the merge statement into the php code) but I got the following errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "user_grace_changes"
BEFORE INSERT ON "grace_period"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

MERGE INTO "grace_period" t1
  USING dual
     ON (t1."id_user" = :new."id_user") 
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET t1."active" = :new."active"
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT( t1."id_user", t1."date_limit", t1."active" )
       VALUES( :new."id_user", :new."date_limit", :new."active" );

END;


insert into "grace_period" ("id_user","date_limit","active")
  VALUES (333, sysdate, 1);

> Informe de error - Error SQL: ORA-04091: la tabla
> PLATAFORMA.grace_period está mutando, puede que el disparador/la
> función no puedan verla ORA-06512: en "PLATAFORMA.user_grace_changes",
> línea 3 ORA-04088: error durante la ejecución del disparador
> 'PLATAFORMA.user_grace_changes' ORA-06512: en
> "PLATAFORMA.user_grace_changes", línea 3 ORA-04088: error durante la
> ejecución del disparador 'PLATAFORMA.user_grace_changes'
> 04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
> *Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
>            this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
>            in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
> *Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Comment: Why not just use a `merge` statement instead of an `insert`? Why do you want to use a trigger?

Comment: Hi Alex ... I dont know why I was trying to use a trigger :( How the merge statement would be then?. Thanks

Comment: Have a look [at the Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm); see if you can put something together, and if you can't make it work, add your attempt to the question (and change the title maybe).

Comment: This is what a got:

MERGE INTO "grace_period" ("id_user","date_limit","active") t1
  USING (SELECT 456 as "id_user", '2014-04-09 12:00:00' as "fecha", 1 as "active"
           FROM dual) t2
     ON (t1."id_user" = t2."id_user") 
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET t1."active" = t2."active",
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT( t1."id_user", t1."date_limit", t1."active" )
       VALUES( t2."id_user", t2."fecha", t2."active" )

Regards

Comment: Please add that to the question as formatted code not as a comment. Is that working and doing what you want? (Actually, if it is then maybe add it as answer; though as the original question was about triggers I'm not quite sure *8-) Unrelated note - why are you using quoted identifiers? Life is easier (and code is easier to read) when you don't.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in a trigger. A row-level trigger can't generally look at or modify the data in the table the trigger is on, which is why you get an ORA-04091 when you try to do a `merge` inside it. You'd get an error if you tried to query the table too. There are workarounds for some scenarios but I don't think they'd work for this case, and would make your schema overly complicated even if they did.

You don't need a trigger for this. You should use a `merge` *instead of* the `insert`. It's a more complicated statement and takes a bit more typing, but once it's in an application that shouldn't matter.

Based on your table structure, instead of this:

```
insert into "grace_period" ("id_user","date_limit","active")
  VALUES (333, sysdate, 1);
```

You can do:

```
MERGE INTO "grace_period" target
USING (
  SELECT 333 AS "id_user", sysdate AS "date_limit", 1 AS "active" FROM dual
) source
ON (target."id_user" = source."id_user") 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET target."active" = source."active", "updated_at" = sysdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT("id", "id_user", "date_limit", "active", "created_at")
  VALUES("grace_seq".NEXTVAL, source."id_user", source."date_limit",
    source."active", sysdate);
```

The values you were passing to the `insert` are now pseudo-columns in the `using` clause, selected from dummy table `dual`. Those are then compared to the existing records in your real table. If a match is found it is updated; otherwise it is inserted.

I've guess you want to set `created_at` and `updated_at` automatically, and also the primary key `id`. You might already have a trigger to set that from a sequence, but here I'm setting it manually from a sequence, so you might need to remove that from the `insert` part if it clashes with what you already have.

So if I run that with the values shown, `333,sysdate,1`, then you get:

```
1 rows merged.

select * from "grace_period";

        id    id_user date_limit     active created_at updated_at
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1        333 09-APR-14           1 09-APR-14
```

If I run it again, but with `active` set to 0, then you get:

```
1 rows merged.

select * from "grace_period";

        id    id_user date_limit     active created_at updated_at
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1        333 09-APR-14           0 09-APR-14  09-APR-14
```

If you want to make it easier to call you could wrap it in a procedure:

```
create procedure merge_grace (p_id_user "grace_period"."id_user"%type,
  p_date_limit "grace_period"."date_limit"%type,
  p_active "grace_period"."active"%type) as
begin
  merge into "grace_period" target
  using (
    select p_id_user as "id_user", p_date_limit as "date_limit",
      p_active as "active"
    from dual
  ) source
  on (target."id_user" = source."id_user") 
  when matched then
    update set target."active" = source."active", "updated_at" = sysdate
  when not matched then 
    insert("id", "id_user", "date_limit", "active", "created_at")
    values("grace_seq".nextval, source."id_user", source."date_limit",
      source."active", sysdate);
end;
/
```

Then calling it is more friendly:

```
exec merge_grace(333, sysdate, 1);

anonymous block completed

select * from "grace_period";

        id    id_user date_limit     active created_at updated_at
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3        333 09-APR-14           1 09-APR-14             

exec merge_grace(333, sysdate, 0);

anonymous block completed

select * from "grace_period";

        id    id_user date_limit     active created_at updated_at
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3        333 09-APR-14           0 09-APR-14  09-APR-14
```

---

I mentioned this in a comment, but I would really seriously reconsider [using quoted identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm) as they make code harder to read and write. Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database object names, as that document says. There doesn't seem to be any obvious reason to have everything forced to lower-case. Of course, that's easier if you're creating a new schema and don't have lots of existing objects to worry about...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code ..

```
CREATE TABLE "grace_period" (
    "id"    NUMBER(11)  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "id_user"   NUMBER(20)  NOT NULL,

    "active"    NUMBER(11)

);
```

insert into grace_period
values(1,123,1)

```
create or replace PROCEDURE insert_on_grace(
        p_id      NUMBER,
        p_id_user NUMBER,
        p_active  NUMBER)
    AS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO grace_period VALUES
        (p_id,p_id_user,p_active);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
      UPDATE grace_period
      SET "active" =1
      WHERE "id"   =p_id ;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Erros');
    END;
```

It's working nicely.